# how can i see raw serial data from a bluetooh connection on a mac?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, bluetooth

I want to see the data flow from a connected bluetooth device.  I figure I should be able to see the raw data in the terminal somehow, but I cannot seem to find out how to do this.  I'm running Snow Leopard on a MacBook

Thanks.

Comment: Try OSX's PacketLogger - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863088/bluetooth-sniffer-preferably-mac-osx

Answer (score 0):

I've only done this on Linux, but it should be possible with a MACBook (It runs BSD AFAIK) but here goes:

If you can get to a shell prompt AND if you have the Bluez utilities

just type

`hcidump -X`

at a prompt.

Comment: Mac doesn't have Bluez nor can it be installed due to the differences between the Linux BT api and Apple's BT API.