# Simulating bluetooth devices on iOS simulator / Xcode

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ios-simulator

I am testing some code to connect bluetooth devices on an iPhone app that works with WatchKit. As Apple watch is not out yet I need to rely on the simulator/Xcode to test it. **Is there a way to simulate a bluetooth device on Xcode and link this to the iPhone simulator and WatchKit extension processes?** I know how to attach the Watch app to the iPhone simulator but I am unaware of any technique to simulate BLE.

Comment: No, simulator doesn't allow of use of Bluetooth now.

Comment: Is there any way to use Bluetooth explorer to sniff the devices and connect it to the simulator? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863088/bluetooth-sniffer-preferably-mac-osx

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

get yourself a BLE USB dongle.
you need to be on OS X 10.7 and you need also to set an NVRAM setting:

```
$sudo nvram bluetoothHostControllerSwitchBehavior="never"
```

Comment: Does this allow the iOS Simulator to detect BLE signal?

Comment: @mm24  Yes it does

Comment: Hi BriniH, I wonder do you know how to use my Mac Pro keyboard used as a bluetooth keyboard of simulator iPhones in Xcode? I need to handle the bluetooth keyboard input in my app, but I don't have a real magic keyboard now.